# Display value of view columns on jenkins using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nodename

I'm using jenkins pipeline. I can get the value of the node name that my job is running on like this: echo "NODE_NAME = ${env.NODE_NAME}"

Now I want to display the value of NODE_NAME on view of jenkins UI in the red circle below. How can I do it? Plz help.
[Jenkins view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/855Vu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pipeline is not considered to be "built on" any particular machine as it can be using zero to many nodes. That is the reason why those plugins that visualize build nodes does not discover anything. The incompatibility between pipeline and old-style jobs is apparent on multiple places (node build history, build page, etc.).